# Autocomplete google api places in bootstrap modal not appearing even in DOM

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have created simple input which will hold google places api `autocomplete`.

```
<input #search placeholder="Search location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control">
```

It works perfectly fine. But when I combine it with bootstrap modal it does not appear, neither in `DOM`. I have searched for differnet solutions which in short words ask me to put css class on element but the problem it's not in `DOM`, ie.

```
.pac-container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1051 !important;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

but it does not work.

I am wondering why putting it in bootstrap modal effects in not appearing even in `DOM`? 
Why putting higher `z-index` even on frame of that input also does not work?

I run modal in that way:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(content);
        if (data) {
            modalRef.componentInstance.data = data;
        }
```

which `modalService` is from `import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`

My autocomplete is also places in `ng-template`.

```
<ng-template #forNewEvent>
    <a [ngClass]="{'pt-0': newEvent}" class="card-body my-auto">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-content-center align-items-center my-3">
            <div *ngIf="!canAction" class="d-flex te-pointer">
                <h6 class="text-uppercase text-muted mb-0 d-flex align-items-center mr-3">
                    Organizer:
                </h6>
                <div class="avatar avatar-sm mr-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/avatars/avatar-1.jpg" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
                </div>
                <h6 class="text-uppercase text-muted mb-0 d-flex align-items-center">
                    {{event.owner.name}}
                </h6>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--        <form [formGroup]="newEventForm" (ngSubmit)="onNewEventSubmit()">-->
        <div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span (click)="d.toggle()" class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fe fe-calendar"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input (click)="d.toggle()"
                       [(ngModel)]="model"
                       ngbDatepicker
                       #d="ngbDatepicker"
                       type="text" class="form-control form-control-flush" placeholder="When the Event should be?">
            </div>
            <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-flush" id="title" placeholder="Event title">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input #search placeholder="Search location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-label-group">
                <textarea class="form-control form-control-flush" id="description" placeholder="Event description"></textarea>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
            </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: How are you creating bootstrap modal?

Comment: please see the question. I already edited so that I also put those information

Comment: Is your autocomplete element placed inside ng-template?

Comment: yes it is. i also edited the question

Comment: check this: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3825